# Ansible - combining two variables adds [u...] to one of them

Tags: jquery, python, json, ansible

I am trying to combine two strings together. one is extracted from set_facts and the other one is defined as a variable in the playbook. But when i run debug on. i am getting extra characters like `[u'` and `']`
but not getting the clean output.

This is the result I want:

```
final_list: usera,userb,userc,userd,usere,userf
```

But this is the result which I am getting:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_list": "[u'usera,userb,userc'],userd,usere,userf"
}
```

Here is my playbook:

```
    - vars:
        list_2: "userd,usere,userf"
    - set_fact:
        list_1="{{ parent_hgdata.json|json_query("parameters[?name=='usernames'].value") }}"

 - name: verify list 1 output
      debug:
        var: list_1

### The above task gives me the right output for list_1

    - name: Combining list _1 and list_2
      set_fact: 
        final_list: "{{ list_1 }},{{ list_2 }}"   

    - name: Now verify the final_list
      debug: 
        var: final_list
```

Now When i debug the final_list. it gived me the unclean output

```
"final_list": "[u'usera,userb,userc'],userd,usere,userf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_1` is a list object, `list_2` is a string.

If you want to have a string in the end, you need to first to convert the list to a string using [`join` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7) and then concatenate with the remaining parts:

```
set_fact:
  final_list: "{{ list_1 | join(‘,’) }},{{ list_2 }}"
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked. yay!. techraf, you are amazing .  Thanks for the explanation as well :)